# How to link two tables by third?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables:

1) book: id (primary), name

2) shop: code (unique, not primary), name

3) book_shop: book_id, shop_id (code), price

I want to get shops in book like

```
book.getShop();
```

How to link this entities?

I tried:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book", schema = "example")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BookShop> bookShop;
}
```

.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop", schema = "example")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Shop {
    @Id
    private int code;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BookShop> bookShop;
}
```

.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_shop", schema = "example")
public class BookShop  implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private Book book;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    private Shop shop;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private int fromDate;
}
```

This code return empty set: Book book = bookRepostiory.getById(1).get().getBookShop()

Comment: [@ManyToMany and @JoinTable](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=WnM4XNTZJsWHwPAPquCAwAI&q=jpa+manyToMany+join+table&oq=jpa+manyToMany+join+table&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30l8.11312.18735..18872...3.0..0.106.2724.19j9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i20i263.CGaMmb03mIA)

Comment: In book_shop there is field price. How i can get this field if use ManyToMany with JoinTable?

Comment: Part of the google search result, second in my result list -> [The best way to map a many-to-many association with extra columns when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the many to many mapping implement like as below remove your book_shop table,

add this code to  shop entity,

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinTable(name = "book_shop",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id", nullable = false)})
  private Set<Book> bookList = null;
```

add this code to book entity,

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
mappedBy ="bookList")
    private Set<Shop> shopList=null;
```

if any issue inform!!

Comment: whats the provide error, can you give me screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, first - initialize the set in the entity

```
private Set<BookShop> bookShop = new HashSet<>();
```

Second, add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to your association, for e.g.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Error: Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception.